# ¿Que codigo necesito para saber si mi app android tiene internet movil (datos) o wifi?

Tags: android, aplicación-web

Estoy programando una aplicación android híbrida, en la cual necesito saber si el usuario (teléfono) está conectado a algún tipo de red, ya sea datos móviles o wi-fi, y en caso de que **NO EXISTA** esta conexión la aplicación lanzará un ***Toast*** en donde pide que se verifique la conexión.

Comment: Hola Rose y bienvenida a SO en español. ¿Podrías explicarnos a qué te refieres con aplicación híbrida?

Comment: Si te decantas hacia phonegap hay plugins para detectar si hay internet activado

Answer (score 2):

Actualización Enero 2020:

#### **A partir de Android 10 el uso de la clase NetWorkInfo y sus métodos es obsoleto, ahora se debe hace uso de la clase ConectivityManager y metodo getNetworkCapabilities() o Clase NetworkCapabilities**

Detecta si estas conectado a red Wifi.

```
  public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (connectivityManager != null) {
            NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
            if (capabilities != null) {
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI");
                    return true;
                } 
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Detecta si estas conectado a internet móvil (datos).

```
public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
        if (capabilities != null) {
            if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

Puedes detectar conectividad, usando este método:

```
private static ConnectivityManager manager;

    public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && 

networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Para detectar si la red es de tipo WiFi 
 :

```
public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
}
```

o si es de tipo Móvil :

```
  public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
    }
```

Simplemente llama los metodos en una sentencia IF, por ejemplo para comprobar conectividad, si no existe mostramos un [Toast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3504538/250260):

```
if (isOnline(getApplicationContext())){
    //existe conectividad
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Existe conectividad", 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    //No existe conectividad.
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No existe conectividad", 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay unas cuestiones en tu pregunta, tenía `android-studio` como etiqueta pero explicas que es una app híbrida, si es con Android Studio entonces es nativa y para checar la conectividad es esto:

Existen muchos ejemplos, uno de ellos...

```
public class RevisarInternet{


private static final String TAG = RevisarInternet.class.getSimpleName();



public static boolean ConexionDisponible(Context context)
{
    NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager)
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (info == null)
    {
         Log.d(TAG,"No hay conexión de internet");
         return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(info.isConnected())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG," Conexión a internet");
            return true;
        }

    }
}
    }
```

En tu actividad que deseas mostrar el `Toast`:

```
if(RevisarInternet.ConexionDisponible(Activity.this)) 
                {

                       // Muestras tu toast que si hay conexión
                }   
               else
                {
                     // Muestras tu toast que no hay conexión
                }
```

Agregas esto a tu *Manifest*:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
```

Ahora, si es una aplicación híbrida (Tomando en cuenta que es ***Ionic*** porque no especificas que tecnología usas) puedes testear la red:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp', ['ionic'])
    .run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            if(window.Connection) {
                if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
                    $ionicPopup.confirm({
                        title: "Internet Desconectado",
                        content: "No tienes internet."
                    })
                    .then(function(result) {
                        if(!result) {
                            ionic.Platform.exitApp();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Respuestas obtenidas de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866035/android-show-a-message-if-no-internet-connection-and-continue-to-check) y [aquí.](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/06/check-network-connection-with-ionicframework/)